# How to create human readable time stamp?

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp, datetime-conversion

In my PHP program, I'm using [`$_SERVER`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to log the page's date visited:

```
$dateStamp = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
```

The result is that the `$dateStamp` variable contains a [Unix timestamp](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) like:

```
1385615749
```

What's the simplest way to convert it into a human-readable date/time (with year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds)?

Comment: strtotime function will do ryt?

Comment: You can modify the excellent [`human_time_diff`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2768466674321dac7f0fd3deff765796113cc4f9/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2164) function from wordpress.

Comment: Can anyone verify I am picking the right answer?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This number is called [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Functions like [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) can accept it as the optional second parameter to format it in readable time.

Example:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']);
```

If you omit the second parameter the current value of [`time()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) will be used.

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: This seems to be the simplest one.

Comment: php looks like this <php? Date('Y-m-d H:i:s', ['timestamp']) ?>

Answer (score 2):

Your functional approch to convert timestamp into Human Readable format are as following

```
function convertDateTime($unixTime) {
   $dt = new DateTime("@$unixTime");
   return $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}

$dateVarName = convertDateTime(1385615749);

echo $dateVarName;
```

Output :-

```
2013-11-28 05:15:49
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://codepad.org/efNaSVHl)</kbd>

Comment: @JimThio, Roopenda: The @ sign is not for error suppressing. [It's the format specifier `DateTime` uses for a unix timestamp.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php) If it actually did suppress errors, that would be a bad idea anyway.

Comment: @Roopenda I wasn't saying to remove it. Now you've removed it the code won't work at all.

Comment: @Boann thanks for update me. I was thought I have done something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();

$dateStamp = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];

$date->setTimestamp($dateStamp);

echo $date->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
<?php
$date = date_create();
$dateStamp = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
date_timestamp_set($date, $dateStamp);
echo date_format($date, 'U = D-M-Y H:i:s') . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: I am suspicious. Why do you use both date_create and date_timestamp_set?

Comment: $date = date_create(); Return a new DateTime object and date_timestamp_set(); Set the date and time based on a Unix timestamp

Answer (score 0):

`REQUEST_TIME` - It is  unix timestamp - The timestamp of the start of the request.

```
$dateStamp = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
echo date('d m Y', $dateStamp);
```

OR

```
$date = new DateTime($dateStamp);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will work for you

```
$dateStamp = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];

echo date('d-M-Y H:i:s',strtotime($dateStamp));
```