# Convert Unix TimeStamp into "x seconds ago"

Tags: php, unix

so I have a table which lists chat messages in my game server (chat messages are stored in a database) and I have a UNIX timestap like this (for example) 1455749769

Does anyone know how I can use php to convert the timestamp so it echos how long ago the chat message was for example: "5 Seconds Ago"

Here is my table

```html
$name=$row['client_name'];
$time=$row['msg_time'];
$name=htmlentities($name);
        echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td> $time </td>";
 echo "<td><a href='http://144.76.158.173/ech/user.php?id=".$row["client_id"]."' > $name </a></td>";
 echo "<td> $msg </td>";
 echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
echo "</div>";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I've already aswered this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34988193/how-to-change-mysql-date-to-ago-in-php/34988412#34988412 Make sure to search before asking

Comment: Yes but in that question his format in the database is 2016-01-21 23:15:00 whilst mine is like this 1455749769

Comment: Touché, point on your part. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the current time and substract:

```
$now = time();
//results into an unix like 1455750460
//then just substract:

$diff = $now - $time
// gives you the passed seconds

//readable
echo date('H:i:s', $diff);
```

Comment: Thank you,
Second question, do you know how I can get it to do like 1m 5s ago and 1h 1m 5s ago and 1d 1h 1m 5s ago ? :)

Comment: i edited the example above. have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258294/how-to-create-human-readable-time-stamp

Answer (score 2):

The timestamp is seconds since the Epoch, so just get the current timestamp and subtract:

```
$seconds = time() - $time
```

Comment: Thank you, Second question, do you know how I can get it to do like 1m 5s ago and 1h 1m 5s ago and 1d 1h 1m 5s ago ? :)

Comment: @JonnyMackell: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273804/convert-seconds-into-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds